# Is "Intercept" ensuring that the request is not sent to the server?

Tags: cypress

Is it possible in Cypress to send a request that won't reach the server but instead return a chosen response to us? I consider cy.intercept(), but does this function intercept the request that was sent to the server, along with the response from the server, which can then be modified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are various hooks that can be used for this purpose.

In the following example I use the `before:response` to make a modification to the response.

To explore the way the hooks work, I use a `win.fetch(...)` which creates the request independently  of the application under test.

```js
cy.intercept('/todos/*', (req) => {
  req.on('before:response', (res) => {

    // take a look at the actual server response
    console.log('before:response', res.body)  

    // make a modification to that response
    res.body.title = 'modified in before:response'
  })
})
.as('todos')

// make a dummy call to your API to check the intercept is functional
cy.window().then(win => win.fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1'))


cy.wait('@todos')
  .then(({request, response}) => {

    // take a look at the modified server response
    console.log('wait', response.body)

    // should contain the changed data
    expect(response.body.title).to.eq('modified in before:response')
  })
```

You can see *res modified* tag in the Cypress log

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Yes, if ***your app*** sends a request to the server you can provide a fixture or a static response (in the test code) and that will prevent the request going to the server.

[StaticResponse](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#staticResponse-StaticResponse)

```js
const staticResponse = {
  /* some StaticResponse properties here... */
}

cy.intercept('/projects', staticResponse)
```

If you want to send a request from the ***test*** with `cy.request()` then no, you cannot use `cy.intercept()` to catch that request.

If you want to use `cy.request()` but have it not go to the server - what is the point of that? Just don't send any request.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to modify the response from the server, [you can do that using `cy.intercept()`'s intercepted responses object.](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#Intercepted-responses)

```js
cy.intercept('/foo', (req) => {
  req.continue((res) => {
    res.body.bar = true; // modify the value of `bar` in the response body.
    res.send();
  });
});
```